# Change setting in Notepad++ to default R language

Tags: r, notepad++

I have some `R` code files with extension `.R` and use `Notepad++` as default application to work on them.

However when I double click an `.R` file to open in `Notepad++`, it opens as plain text file as symbol highlighting for `R` is not applied as default. I therefore have to manually chose language as `R` from the Language tab.

Is there any way to set default behaviour of `Notepad++` such that when it opens a `.R` file, it will directly apply default style for `R`?

I have gone through various advices e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/58672/how-to-set-the-default-language-in-notepad and tried to follow advices there, but still could not apply default setting of `R` to `.R` file directly. My setting configuration looks like below :

[image]

It would be really helpful if someone can point to the right approach set default behaviour of `Notepad++` so that it will apply settings for `R` language directly to `.R` file.

I am using `Windows 10` as OS.

Comment: I can't reproduce, unfortunately. I installed notepad++ using its standard installer with no changes. When I open a pre-existing `.R` file, *Language >> R >> R* is selected, and when I create a new file, the moment I assign the file name to be `.R`, the language is similarly selected. With that, syntax highlighting is correct for R. Perhaps you've inadvertently (or historically) changed N++'s default behavior?

Comment: Is there any hard setting available to overwrite current functionality?

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten this issue.

I resolved it by <strike>deleting</strike> disabling Rebol language in Notepad++. After I've done that the R language was detected.

It's not the best answer if you use Rebol language but I don't use nor know it.

Settings / Preferences.../ Language / disabled items (or hidden in some translations)

Comment: Good find. I had never heard of nor worked with the Rebol language, so didn't think to look there. The file extensions for that are `.r` and `.reb`, and I can see how ambiguity might be an issue. (Granted, in my case I have both R and Rebol in the list and my instance has no problem auto-selecting R, but ... perhaps somewhere order of languages is important.)

Comment: @phili_b how can I delete the Robot language?

Comment: @Bogaso: I edited my message: deleting -> disabling . You have to go in "Settings / Preferences.../ Language / disabled items"

Answer (score -1):

[Screenshot of language selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOh1L.png) You should be able to select language from the drop down on the top row. Although I recently made the switch to VSCode - would recommend.

Edit:1 You can use VSCode with extension installed `R` then you can refer official documentations from extension provider

Comment: *"From the drop down on the top row"* is a bit vague. Please demonstrate with screenshots and/or clearer specifics.

Comment: Added edit, please see above

Comment: From the OP: *"manually chose language as R from the Language tab"*, meaning that the OP already knows how to do this. The issue is why is it not being done automatically.